# ScrollView does not work with ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout

`ScrollView` does not work, I have a layout with some components like `EditText`, and when I'm typing something `EditText` keyboard rises, and along the component, however it appears above the other, the `ScrollView` does not respond to their function. 
Already googled, and found some similar problems, but none solved my problem.

Below my layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDescricaoDocumento"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtDescricaoDocumento"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edtDescricaoDocumento"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Descrição:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                    ...
```

And my `manifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".LancarDocumentoAcaoActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Do you want scroll on entire layout or on edittext/textview ?

Comment: I want scroll on entire layout, as the gmail app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things I've tried this without the **relative layout** inside of the scroll view...and scroll view worked perfectly.

1.Is relative layout necessary inside a linear layout? Try removing it if not.

2.Is the attribute WindowSoftInputMode necessary for the corresponding class if not you will have the soft keyboard covering view elements like it is mentioned.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: 1. LinearLayout is not necessary for me. 
2. WindowSoftInputMode is corresponding to the correct class.

Comment: Removed, and the problem continues.

Comment: Ok have you tried using a typical linear layout if your just showing textviews/editText views linear layout is best choice...update your code with mine:

Comment: Ok ...update your code with mine ive dumped it here [link](http://codedumptum.tumblr.com) linear layouts work best in vertical or horizontal element arrangements.Relative layouts is just as effective but is unnecessary for what you want to achieve

Comment: First thank you, but the problem for linear change is that I my components are all lined up as they should, and with linear'll have to refactor and the tree will get big

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem with your help, but I kept using relative